# IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON in a unique non-clustered Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a unique non-clustered index in SQL Server that has IGNORE_DUP_KEY. Here is the index:

```
/****** Object:  Index [TIMESTAMP_NONCLUSTERED]    Script Date: 1/7/2015 1:30:22 PM ******/
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TIMESTAMP_NONCLUSTERED] ON [dbo].[Events]
(
    [Timestamp] ASC,
    [EventID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Type],
    [Category],
    [Node],
    [DoID],
    [AssociatedDoID],
    [OpaqueData]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Is this the best way to ignore duplicate inserts? In addition, if you restart SQL Server will this still work since it is a non-clustered index? What will SQL Server compare first, timestamp then EventID? How does SQL does it is it like a query where SQL Server will look at timestamp then EventID?

EventID is in guid form.

Comment: IMO something is a bit fishy with the table design - you have a table named `Events` with a Guid column `EventId` which cannot be used as a primary Key, and even after combining it with another field it still isn't unique enough to be used as a unique NC index?

Comment: The clients inserting to the table has a retry mechanism and it needs to go through the network. There is some instances (less likely to happen in a normal situation) that the client retries the same Event to be inserted.

Comment: @StuartLC , you have any idea if SQL Server will look first on the Timestamp before the EventID?

Comment: Yes, indexes are evaluated in the order left to right. One thing to note is that the clustereed key (as used by the clustered index) is present on all non-clustered indexes. So, for instance, if EventId was a primary key in its own right, and was used as the clustered index, that a NC index for Timestamp wouldn't need to explicitly add `EventID` to the NC index.

Comment: Aside from smelly design as @StuartLC mentioned, to solve this problem I would use MERGE statement to insert or update the row, depending if it already exists or not.

Comment: Okay, but given that it will have millions of billions of rows, will it still work? and given that the timestamp is combined with the EventID will SQL Server look at timestamp first before EventID?

Comment: thanks for all the suggesetions. I know it is kind of a smelly design but to add integrity and other clients sending from embedded and windows platform design, there will be retries happening during a network communication failure. btw how can i add a check on you answers?